# Why does my symfony php security not work?

Tags: symfony, security

I'm facing some issues with my code and the login feature, and I'm quite perplexed as to why it's not working as expected. Despite investing a considerable amount of time and effort into this.

To begin with, I followed the standard procedure for creating a functional login system. I used the command

`php bin/console make:user` To hash my passwords I use `php bin/console security:hash-password`

Now, let's focus on the Login Controller, a crucial piece of the puzzle. Inside this controller, I retrieve the last authentication error using the $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError() method. My expectation was that this approach would give me the desired outcome, but unfortunately, things haven't gone as planned.

Moreover, I obtain the last username using $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(), thinking it would work smoothly. However, to my disappointment, the login feature continues to elude me, causing frustration and confusion.

To give you a clearer picture, here's the structure of my Login Controller:

```
 #[Route('/login', name: 'login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('/bezoeker/login.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'LoginController',
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
```

And Log out

This peculiar construction, which I thought would seamlessly facilitate the logout process, has only led me further down the rabbit hole of confusion and despair.

```
#[Route('/logout', name: 'logout')]
    public function logout(): Response
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this approach hasn't provided the expected results and has only added to my confusion and frustration.

In an effort to find answers, I examined my Twig template, hoping it would shed light on the issues plaguing my login feature. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
{% if error is defined and not error is empty %}
        <div>{{ error.MessageKey | trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
            <label for="username">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/redirect/" />

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>


    </div>
```

I had hoped that error messages would appear and disappear gracefully, akin to passing clouds. However, they persist stubbornly, tormenting me with their unwavering presence.

Moving on, let's delve into the configuration file, `security.yaml`, where I believe the source of the problem may lie. Here's an excerpt from the file:

```
          main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

            logout:
                path: logout
```

Then I made 2 Controllers for Admin And Member

```
php bin/console make controller AdminController 

php bin/console make controller MemberController
```

And add security like this

```
   access_control:
        - { path: '/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: '/member', roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

n this configuration, I've specified the main provider for user authentication. The firewall configuration is set up to handle form-based login, with the login and check paths appropriately defined. The logout path is also specified to facilitate user logouts.

Additionally, I've implemented access control rules, designating certain paths as accessible only to users with specific roles such as ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_MEMBER.

Lastly, let's discuss the redirection logic in the redirectAction method within one of my controllers. Here's an example:

```
    #[Route('/redirect', name: '_target_path')]
    public function redirectAction(Security $security): Response
    {
        if ($security ->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin');
        }
        if ($security ->isGranted('ROLE_MEMBER')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_member');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('/');
    }
```

Now, despite my best efforts and the seemingly correct implementation of these components, I find myself unable to pinpoint the exact cause of the errors and malfunctions I'm experiencing. It's a disheartening predicament, and I'm genuinely at a loss as to where I might have gone wrong.

If you have any insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in unraveling this conundrum.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please describe explicitly what are the errors you see, it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: A `^` character may be missing in `access_control`, compare it to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security.html#form-login).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.